# parallel transport along $W^{1,2}$-curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, reference-request

Let $c$ be a $W^{1,2}$-curve into a (compact Riemannian) manifold $Q,$ defined on some open interval $I$. Let $t_0\in I$ and $\xi_0\in T_{c(t_0)}Q$ be arbitrary. I am looking for a citeable reference for the following statement: There is a unique $W^{1,2}$-vector field $\xi$ along $c$ satisfying

(i) $\nabla_{\dot{c}}\xi=0$ a.e. on $I$

(ii) $\xi(t_0)=\xi_0.$

Notice that the statement above could be deduced from the standard Picard-Lindelöf theorem if $c$ was sufficiently regular (i.e. e.g. $c$ was $C^1$).

Comment: $W^{1,2}$ means one derivative in $L_2$?

Comment: @Deane: That's correct!

Comment: And you know how to prove it but would like a reference?

Comment: I know a 40 year old refence in German. There the authors claim the statement to be well-known (and still give a proof in the appendix). Hence I thought there might be an English reference as well (since I get the feeling - while reading the paper - that the statement is not original to the paper)

Comment: Since $W^{1,2} \subset C^0$ and (i) is a linear first ODE, the usual rewrite-as-integral-equation proof seems to work and is rather straightforward. I don't recall seeing this written down anywhere, but, if I'm correct on this, it's easy to verify and summarize.

Comment: @Deane: If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be inclined to accept it as an answer. (In particular since the proof outline you described is essentially the proof in the reference - up to clever choosing of norms...) As an aside: I stumbled upon Caratheodory's existence theorem - is there a relation?

Comment: Orbicular, OK. Also, Caratheodory's theorem doesn't seem relevant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $W^{1,2} \subset C^0$ and the zero-th order term of (i) depends linearly on $\dot{c} \in L^2$, the usual rewrite-as-integral-equation proof seems to work and is rather straightforward. I don't recall seeing this written down anywhere, but it's easy to verify and summarize.

Answer (score 4):

You will find a proof in Appendix D (Theorem D.1)
of my book `A Tour of SubRiemannian Geometry'.
It may not look like what you want  at first glance, since
that theorem  is stated in a  more general context,    applicable  to parallel transport
in principal bundles.  Take the  vector fields $X_a$   there
to be the  standard   framing of  the horizontal space 
associated to the Levi-Civita connection, as viewed as a
a distribution  on the   orthonormal frame bundle of  your $Q$.